# Mxgraph Reactjs not import mxgraph library

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph

I try to use mxgraph with react project. But I can not use mxgraph with react.

I install mxgraph:

```
npm install mxgraph
```

Then I wrote:

```
import {
   mxGraph,
   mxGraphHandler,
   mxGraphModel,
       ...
} from "mxgraph";
```

---

```
InitGraph =()={
   let container = document.createElement("div");
   this.setContainerStyle();

   let model = new mxGraphModel();
   let graph = new mxGraph(container,model);
}
```

I got an error -->
Uncaught TypeError: mxGraphModel is not a constructor.

But when I use to mxgraph-js it is correctly working.

How I use mxgraph ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this piece of code while initializing. This solved the issue

```
window['mxGraph'] = mxGraph;
window['mxGraphModel'] = mxGraphModel;
const graphEditor = new mxEditor();
window.graphEditor = graphEditor;
graphEditor.createGraph();
let graph = graphEditor.graph
```

Answer (score 0):

mxgraph to import error to use mxgraph-js ref
https://github.com/cloudfroster/mxgraph-js#readme

install pakage

```
npm install mxgraph-js --save
```

import package

```
import {
   mxGraph,
   mxGraphHandler,
   mxGraphModel,
       ...
} from "mxgraph-js";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`npm i --save mxgraph`

```
import MxGraph from "mxgraph/javascript/dist/build.js";

const {
   mxGraph,
   mxGraphHandler,
   mxGraphModel,
       ...
} = new MxGraph();
```

Tested this with `mxgraph@4.2.2`